# How do I pass data between pages in Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to pass data when I route to a new page using  in Gatsby (V2)

I am hoping to then be able to retrieve the data on that page. Is this possible? I have researched this a lot with no luck so I feel as though I must be missing something... Thank you

Comment: In regular react, I would include it in the route then access via this.props.location, for example

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to do something like

< Link to = '/example' data = {id: 'xyz'} /> 

So that on the example page
I can render a component with the id prop like
 <Article id = 'xyz'/>

Comment: Pages should get `props.location`, so you can use query params just like in any other React app.

Comment: How would I access the props on the page. when I try to console.log(this) or console.log(this.props) they are both undefined

Comment: If the page is just a function, use the passed argument: `export default ({ location }) => <div>{location.pathname}</div>`

Comment: when i console.log(location) i get "search: ?id=xyz" . Is this the right idea..? I think I'm still confused

Answer (score 8):

If you want to pass props, it can be as simple as the following example from the docs:

```
const PhotoFeedItem = ({ id }) => (
  <div>
    {/* (skip the feed item markup for brevity) */}
    <Link
      to={`/photos/${id}`}
      state={{ fromFeed: true }}
    >
      View Photo
    </Link>
  </div>
)

const Photo = ({ location, photoId }) => {
  if (location.state.fromFeed) {
    return <FromFeedPhoto id={photoId} />
  } else {
    return <Photo id={photoId} />
  }
}
```

The reference in the docs includes an egghead video of the behaviour to clarify it.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#pass-state-as-props-to-the-linked-page

You can also do some advanced routing by using create pages, and  generate pages programatically. This is a bit more advanced but useful if your gatsby app is getting a little complex.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/reach-router-and-gatsby/